# Send param via JS and receive in PHP

Tags: php, angular

Hey trying to send a string parameter (planer) from a TS/JS file to a PHP file. I wanna add it to a path to get all filenames of a directory.

But Im not receiving anything, but a empty string (""). For testing im returning the planer again.

TS/JS:

```
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append('planer', this._planer)

    let http = new XMLHttpRequest()
    http.open('POST', Globals.PATH + '/scripts/getMasterplan.php', true)

    http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    http.send(data)
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$planer = filter_input( INPUT_POST , "planer" , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );   

$planer = htmlspecialchars( $planer );

if( isset($planer) ) {

    $path = '../shared_plaene/master/' . $planer;

    $files = scandir($path);

    echo $planer;
}
else echo 'Error with planer code';

?>
```

Comment: What is the value of $_POST in getMasterPlan.php? And can you confirm through Dev Tools or Postman whether the values are truly being sent?

Comment: How do I find out? Im new to php. I see getMasterplan.php in network tab. But dont see any value

Comment: var_dump($_POST);

I would try what Quentin suggested below. (remove     http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
> ```

FormData will be encoded as multipart data, not URL encoded data.

Since you are lying about the Content-Type, PHP can't parse it correctly.

Remove that line. XHR will set the Content-Type correctly if you don't override it.